# Is there a way to query all my upvotes for a specific tag?

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request, search

I can't find a question I've upvoted. But I know its tags.

I'm aware that I can list all my upvotes, but I want to filter that list. I've upvoted the post 6-9 months ago...

Comment: And it doesn't look like SEDE will be helpful on finding posts you upvoted since it won't let you query anyone's upvotes (not even your own).

Comment: If you're willing to write some code, you could start with [Get a list of posts you've voted on that have been edited](https://stackapps.com/q/6755/29529), but just change it to filter for those that you've upvoted and have the tags you want, rather than those that were edited since you voted. It has the framework for obtaining the data you want and displaying the results. You might need to change the `filter` that it uses when getting data from the SE API, but, overall, doing what you want should be a fairly easy change.

Answer (score 7):

If the only information you have is the tags on the question and that you upvoted it, you will just have to go through your voted posts and look for it. There's no way to filter that within the site's software currently.

Luckily you also know it was 6-9 months ago. You can skip to around the time of that date range (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/users/5175709/honey?tab=votes&sort=upvote&page=5) and then look through the questions, page by page.

Because of this site limitation, I try to make it a habit to favorite or bookmark questions I might want to return to later.

Comment: If the post was deleted afterwards, it won't show up in that list either.

Comment: @SamuelLiew That makes sense, though if the post is deleted then there's *no* way non-mods can search for it, let alone if they know some criteria about it (e.g. tags). And one would *hope* a question upvoted by a 10k+ user would be sufficient quality to not get deleted (though we can never rule out self-deletions by zealous askers for one reason or another...)

Comment: @SamuelLiew Are you saying it wont show up in the favorites if it is deleted?  They should (and do on mine) if you have over 10K rep.

Comment: @NathanOliver I was referring to the link (votes), not favourites.. sorry for the confusion